# One button for several actions

Tags: swift, button

I am having trouble configuring a button that:

- 1st press will do action 1
- 2nd press will do action 2
- 3rd press will do action 3
- 4th press will do action 1
- 5th press will do action 2

...and so on

Is there any way to configure that button?

Thanks

Comment: you can simply have an integer as a counter, in your action function just += 1 the variable and handle each case with a switch case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below in your button action:

```
var counter = 0

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    counter += 1
    switch counter {
    case 1:
        // do your action
    case 2:
        // do your action
    case 3:
       // do your action 
       counter = 0
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st action for 1st press, 2nd action for 2nd press, 3rd action for 3rd press. How do i come back to 1st action with 4th press? I have tried resetting the counter to 0 but it will result in returning to 1st action with 5th press.

Comment: ok I edited the cases, you have to set the counter = 0 in your 3rd case . then the 4th press will come in to your 1st case.

Answer (score 2):

If you were interested in keeping track of the number of clicks while also doing the job of the 3 alternating tasks:

```
var counter : Int = 0

@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    counter+=1
    //print(counter)
    switch counter % 3 {
    case 1:
        // First Action
    case 2:
        // Second Action
    default:
        // Third Action
    }
}
```